# Как сделать кастомный progressbar? swiper js

Tags: javascript, swiper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, подключил библиотеку swiper js, там есть стандартный параметр пагинации как 'progressbar', но он действует совсем не так, то есть он распространяется на всю страницу и идет одним тегом 'span' у которого возрастает параметр scaleX изображения и происходит это резко и не от времени, а мне нужно сделать так же как на картинке выше
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/slider/1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/slider/2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/slider/3.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/slider/4.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/slider/5.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/slider/6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        loop: true,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 2000
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            type: 'progressbar',
        },
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Может вы не к тому элементу подключаетесь. Может к оббертке надо .swiper-wrapper

Comment: Свайпер у меня работает, у меня проблема в прогрессбаре, мне нужно его сделать кастомный, но может быть это можно сделать при помощи уже готового?